# Disable "Press `/` to jump to the search box" in Google

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

Recently I've been getting the message on the bottom left on Google whenever I press `Ctrl + L` to put focus the omnibar ("Press `/` to jump to the search box").

[image: message "Press / to jump to the search box" on Google]

While the animation only slightly annoys me, I would like to turn off this message if easily possible.

Apart from using an adblocker to remove it, is there a setting to do this?

Comment: Ironic: I use a German keyboard which doesn't even have a `/` key (you need to press `Shift + 7`, which does not let me jump to the search bar) and I'm getting this message in the German version of Google as well despite of this.

Comment: It prevents my normal Vimium bindings from working, making this a deal breaker for using google search.